# WiX - Register ComPlus application and Assigning a role to a component

Tags: wix

I have my installer registering my COMPLus component correctly.
I have one last requirement to:
Enforce component level access checks
Under Roles have the “User” Role ticked.

I tried adding a complus:ComPlusCompoent as a child of my ComPlusAssembly but when I do this the installer fails with an error. (See below)
I am not sure what I should put as the CLSID, perhaps this is what is causing the issue?
Can anyone help me out? Explain what I should be putting for the CLSID?

Error and WiX snippet below
Note: 
If I remove the complus:ComPlusComponent element then the installer works fine:
My User ‘ComponentUser” is defined higher up. The role and user are assigned in the component but not ticked.

MSI (s) (68:BC) [16:25:08:579]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSICE31.tmp, Entrypoint: ComPlusInstallExecuteCommit
Action 16:25:08: RegisterComPlusAssemblies. Registering COM+ components
RegisterComPlusAssemblies: DLL: C:\NTApps\MyComPlusCore\ASA.DA.Insurance.dll
ComPlusInstallExecuteCommit:  Error 0x80070490: Failed to find component object
ComPlusInstallExecuteCommit:  Error 0x80070490: Failed to configure components
ComPlusInstallExecuteCommit:  Error 0x80070490: Failed to register assembly, key: ASA.DA.Insurance
ComPlusInstallExecuteCommit:  Error 0x80070490: Failed to register assemblies

```
<complus:ComPlusApplication Id="ASA.NETCoreData3" 
                        Name="ASA.NETCoreData3" 
                        Description="ASA .NET Core Data Components"
                        ApplicationAccessChecksEnabled="yes"
                        AccessChecksLevel="applicationComponentLevel"
                        Authentication="packet"
                        ImpersonationLevel="impersonate"
                        Activation="inproc">

    <complus:ComPlusApplicationRole Id="ASA.NETCoreData3.Role" 
                                Name ="User">
        <complus:ComPlusUserInApplicationRole Id="ASA.NETCoreData3.User" 
                                            User="ComponentUser" />
    </complus:ComPlusApplicationRole>

    <complus:ComPlusAssembly Id="ASA.DA.Insurance" 
                            DllPath="[#ASA.DA.Insurance_dll]"
                            Type="native"
                            RegisterInCommit="yes">
        <complus:ComPlusComponent Id="ASA.DA.Insurance.Com"
                                CLSID="f8a83c94-9ab1-4c4d-8ebc-901aa747ac33"
                                Description="ASA.DA.Insurance.AppInsurance" 
                                ComponentAccessChecksEnabled="yes" >
            <complus:ComPlusRoleForComponent Id="ASA.DA.Insurance.Role" 
                                            ApplicationRole="ASA.NETCoreData3.Role" />
        </complus:ComPlusComponent>
    </complus:ComPlusAssembly>
</complus:ComPlusApplication>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it was the CLSID.
In the previous installers for this compoenet a vb script was used and the projects did not need a static CLSID and so it was specified in the projects.

I needed to add a Guid attribute to the concrete class and then use this guid in the WiX ComPlusComponent clsid.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: How often would thi CLSID Change ?? When I change my assembly version it changes... so I have to change my WiX package everytime we version up. Is there a way of keeping it constant?